# List all cities for a country in Facebook FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

When I query with FQL it list cities different than original names .

```
FB.Data.query(select current_location from user where uid={0}, response.id);
```

For example

```
------------------------------
fql returns  |  Original name
----------------------------
Urfa            Şanlıurfa
-----------------------------
Istanbul        İstanbul
```

İs there any way to list all cities for a Country (Turkey)? A lookup table will be fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why city names are not matched. Although there is no state geo definition in Turkey correct city names are exist  in state part of the current_location. Only you have to make them ascii.

```
current_location.state
```